# Show that the set of accumulation points of $S$ in $\mathbb{R}$ is $\mathbb{R}$

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

Let $S$ be the set of rational numbers whose denominator is divisible by $7$. What is the set of accumulation points of $S$ in $\mathbb{R}$?

Essentially, for any $x\in S$, $x$ can be written as $\frac{m}{7n}$ where $m,n\in \mathbb{N}$. Since rational numbers are dense in $\mathbb{R}$, for any $r\in \mathbb{R}$, there exists a sequence of rationals in form of $\frac{m}{n}$ such that $\frac{m}{n}\to r$. So $\frac{m}{7m}\to \frac{r}{7}$.

Is my reasoning correct? Do I have to take care of $m,n$ being coprime?

Comment: $\mathbb{Q}$ is dense in $\mathbb{R}$, hence $\frac{1}{7}\mathbb{Q}$ is dense in $\mathbb{R}$, too, due to the continuity of $x\mapsto\frac{x}{7}$. Your argument is fine.

Comment: If you do not suppose that $m,n$ are coprimes, then $S=\mathbb Q$ and the result is obvios.

Comment: If $7|m$ then $m/7n \not \in S$ so I think a sentence or two would not be remiss.  However if $m/n \rightarrow r$ then if $m' = m$ if $7\not \mid m$ and $m' = m+1$ if $7|m$ we have $m'/7n \rightarrow r/7$ so we are good.

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio $S \ne \frac 17\mathbb Q = \mathbb Q$,  $\frac {14}{3}*\frac 17 = \frac 23 \in \frac 17\mathbb Q$ but $\frac 23 \not \in S$.

Comment: Obviously the problem wantd you to take the redeced fractions in which the denominator is a multiple of $7$

Comment: @fleablood: I guessed *the* denominator stood for *the* denominator of the **reduced** fraction, of course. Otherwise the problem would simply be asking to prove that $\mathbb{Q}$ is dense in $\mathbb{R}$, and $7$ would have no relevance.

Comment: I think it'd be easy to show $S$ is dense in $\mathbb Q$  and, unless the coffee really hasn't kicked in, density is transitive.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We have to prove that for every real $x$ and $\epsilon>0$ there is $s\in S$ such that $|x-\frac{p}{q}|<2\epsilon$.

To do this first take a rational $r$ such that $|r-x|<\epsilon$( we can do this because $\mathbb Q$ is dense in $\mathbb R$)

We must now find $s\in S$ such that $|r-s|<\epsilon$. If $r\in R$ this is trivial. Otherwise notice $r+ \frac{1}{7n}\in S$ for all $n$. So taking $s=\frac{1}{7n}$ with $|n|>\frac{1}{\epsilon}$ works.

Finally note that $|x-s|\leq|x-r|+|r-s|<2\epsilon$

Answer (score 0):

If we restrict it to the case $$S=\{p/q:p,q\in Z\land 7|q\land \gcd(p,q)=1\}$$ then every real number is an accumulation point of $S.$

Proof:(1). For $A\subset  \mathbb R,$ and $r>0,$ let us say that $A$ is $r$-dense iff $$\forall x \in  \mathbb R\;\exists y\in A\;(\;|x-y|\leq r).$$

(2). If $B=\{r_n: n\in \mathbb N\}$ is a set of positive numbers with $\inf B=0,$ and if $A_n$ is $r_n$-dense for each $n,$ then $A=\cup_{n\in \mathbb N}A_n$ is dense, which makes each member of $\mathbb R$ \ $A$  an accumulation point of $A.$

(3). If, also, $\mathbb R$ \ $A$ is dense, then  for any $x\in A$ and any $s>0$ there exists $y\in (x,x+s)$ \ $A.$ And there exists $z\in A\cap (x,x+r)$.....[because $(x,x+s)$ is a nbhd of $y $ and $y$ is an accumulation point of $A$]..... So any nbhd of $x$ covers $(x,x+s)$ for some $s>0,$ and $A\cap (x,x+s)$ is not empty. So then any $x\in A$ is also an accumulation point of $A.$

(4).Putting this all together: For $n\in \mathbb N $ let $$A_n=\{p/7^n:p\in \mathbb Z\land 7\not | p\}.$$  Now $A_n$ has no upper or lower bound, and if $u,v$ are consecutive members of $A_n,$ then $|u-v|\leq 2/7^n, $ so $A_n$ is $1/7^n$-dense. So $$A=\cup_{n\in \mathbb N}A_n$$ is dense.

Since $A$ is only  countable, every non-empty open interval contains a point not in $A.$ Therefore  we know that $\mathbb R$  \ $A$ is also dense. So every real number is an accumulation point of $A$ by (2) and (3). Since $A\subset S,$ every real is an accumulation point of $S.$

Remark. We can also by the same means show that $\{(2a+1)/2^b:a\in Z \land 2\leq b\in \mathbb N\}$ is dense, and since $A\cap B=\phi,$ we know that $\mathbb R$ \ $A$ is dense without considering the countability of $A.$ Or we could use the fact that the set $J$ of irrational reals is dense, and that $A\cap J$ is empty.